# ConstraintLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to add view to `ConstraintLayout` programmatically. The problem in that that `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` ignore `MATCH_CONSTRAINT` and my view instead of getting max width just centered.

```
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_CONSTRAINT, WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.leftToLeft = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
    lp.topToTop = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
    lp.rightToLeft = guideline.getId();
    lp.bottomToBottom = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;

    textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    textView.setText("Title text");
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    constraintLayout.addView(textView);
```

Comment: Take a look at [ConstraintSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html) documentation.

Comment: Yea, ConstraintSet solved my issue, but this is strange that layoutparams doesent works as expected.

Comment: yeah...this is weird..`LayoutParams` is to working for this

Answer (score 6):

```
textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setId(R.id.text_id);
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.clone(constraintLayout);
set.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
set.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
set.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
set.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, guideline.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
textView.setText("Title text");
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

constraintLayout.addView(textView);
set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Xml Value for ID

```
<item name="text_id" type="id"/>
```